# I have 250 rep but why is there no 250 option in the bounty drop down?

Tags: support, bounties

The following screenshot tells you my question much better.

[image]

Is it a bug or a by-design feature?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The minimum amount of reputation possible is 1.

As such, to be able to offer a bounty of 250, you will need 251 reputation.

Comment: The minimum rep should be 0. :-)

Comment: @PSTikZ - There are reasons it isn't. And it won't be changed./